# 550 Administrative Prohibition SMTP error

Tags: smtp

I have been having a problem with this belimy hair for not sending products as advertised.  Not able to return or contact.  I have marked as not reputable business and I send email attachmented every time user it but it is still up.

email sent successfully but didn't deliver to reception email. It shows some failure error

550 Administrative Prohibition

Can any body guide me that where is mistake.

thanks

Comment: Automatically Detect Configuration (recommended) 
 Local Mail Exchanger
 Backup Mail Exchanger
 Remote Mail Exchanger

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The message means that for some reason the system administrator on one end or another refused to allow the message to be transmitted. Additional details, if there are any, may provide a clue as to which end the prohibition is on. But it's not an error -- it's a deliberate effort to stop the message.

Comment: can u guide me where i can solve this issue i mean in php.ini file or any command for email sender in linux machine fedora 8

Comment: To solve this issue, contact the Email Administrator of the domain that returned this error and ask her why she refused to accept your message.